# Service Worker is caching resources without me asking it to

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm registering a service worker which essentially subscribes to the `fetch` event, and returns the cached version of my resources, if they exist.  Viewing my network tab, it appears as though resources are coming back from the service worker, even though I've cached literally zero files.

[image]

Is this normal?

(obviously the plan was to cache files, I'm just trying to build this step by step)

---

I'm registering my service worker like this

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('swRoot.js').then(() => {
        console.log('registered');
    }, err => console.log(err));
}
```

The entirety of `swRoot.js` is this

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('hello');
});

console.log('ADDING FETCH at root level');
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('fetching ->', event.request);
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response) {
                // Cache hit - return response
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't represents that the results are coming from cache. It only shows that the response is coming from **service worker**. Now if the result is coming from service worker it could either be from cache or from fetch event. In your case it is clearly coming fetch event.